# Animating SliverAppBar or AppBar = Changing background color while scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is it possible to change the background of Appbar or SliverAppbar while scrolling?.
I have these requirements for a `SliverAppbar` or `Appbar` and I don't find a way to solve them.

- At the first page, the Appbar or SliverAppBar didn't have a background color or transparent.
- When scrolling the page the Appbar or SliverAppBar changing from didn't have a background color to have a background color.

[This the first appearance of the Appbar or SliverAppbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5qaP.jpg)

[This the AppBar or SliverAppbar appearance when scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tOUh.jpg)

**Here the example that i want to achieve**

[image: Here the example that i want to achieve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If you want to use `FlexibleSpaceBar` you can specify a background color for it, and when the app bar is expanded, you will see the `FlexibleSpaceBar`'s background color. For example:

```
      SliverAppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        expandedHeight: 200,
        pinned: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

**Method 2:**

If you don't want to use `FlexibleSpaceBar` (or if you don't want to expand/stretch the `AppBar`), you can use `SliverLayoutBuilder` to check whether scrolling has occurred. If `constraints.scrollOffset > 0`, that means the user has scrolled at least a little bit. For example:

```
      SliverLayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, constraints) {
          final scrolled = constraints.scrollOffset > 0;
          return SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: scrolled ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
            pinned: true,
          );
        },
      )
```

Using this method, if you want to do some transition when scrolling, it's easy too - just get the current `scrollOffset` and generate a color based on that.

Comment: hey, I'm using method 2 and it worked and I really thank you. and I implement it to the icons and their work but how to changing the logo color at middle of the sliverappbar?

Comment: @ezraRahardian It's the same idea, you can just `:?` to set it to different color based on `scrolled` variable.